# InvalidConfigurationException with FOSFacebookBundle

Tags: php, symfony

Following the [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/README.md) in the bundle, I get this exception:

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "fos_facebook"
>   under "security.firewalls.main"

It looks like documentation in #6 is wrong, but I see (also here in StackOverflow) that many people used "fos_facebook" option succesfully.
My Symfony version is 2.0.9 (currently last one)

Comment: looks like a configuration issue.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm following the bundle's docs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that you have configured the factories option correctly, like so:

```
security:
  factories:
    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"
```